# Can I dispose of an SqlConnection through a SqlCommand.Disposed event?

Tags: c#, .net

Can I attach an event to an SqlCommand.Disposed event that will dispose of the SqlCommand's connection? Here is the code I am testing:

```
    public static SqlCommand GetCommand(string query, SqlParameter[] paramCollection, bool isStoredProcedure)
    {
        return new DBSettings().CreateCommand(query, paramCollection, isStoredProcedure);
    }

    public SqlCommand CreateCommand(string query, SqlParameter[] paramCollection, bool isStoredProcedure)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        if (paramCollection.Length > 0)
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(paramCollection);
        if (isStoredProcedure)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Disposed += new EventHandler(cmd_Disposed);
        return cmd;
    }

    protected void cmd_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = (SqlCommand)sender;
        cmd.Connection.Dispose();
    }
```

I want to be able to call the static method GetCommand in a using block and when it is done, dispose of the connection like this:

```
        using (SqlCommand cmd = GetCommand(query, paramCollection, false))
        {
            //code to execute
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method should work, but it is really counter-intuitive and I would recommend to rethink the design. Dependant object (command) controlling lifetime of the object it depends on (connection)? What if you want to run more commands on the same connection? What about transactions?

Comment: The .NET Framework automatically caches open SqlConnections when the connection string is the same. So if one connection is open and another SqlCommand executes, it will use the same connection. I have been using the code and it seems to execute quite fast. But I will take your advice. This is what I am changing the delegat to: cmd.Disposed += delegate { if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Executing && conn.State != ConnectionState.Fetching && conn.State != ConnectionState.Connecting) { conn.Dispose(); } };

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine.
You can test it by setting a breakpoint in the `Disposed` handler.

You can also shorten it using anonymous methods:

```
cmd.Disposed += delegate { conn.Dispose(); };
```